# How to get programs to show their size in the control panel?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall

In Windows' Control Panel when I go to uninstall a program many do not show their size. Why does this happen and how can I change it? Even Microsoft Office doesn't show it's size which surprises me because it's a reputable program.

Answer (score 2):

The Add/Remove Programs applet first looks for the optional registry entry at 
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*SomeProgram*\EstimatedSize`.

If that key can't be found it looks in the `Program Files` directory for a subdirectory name sharing at least two words in common with the application's display name (stored in the mandatory registry entry `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*SomeProgram*\DisplayName`) and reports the size of that directory.

If both of these methods fail then no size is displayed.

[Further reading](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx)

Comment: Windows 7 has dropped the file searching method. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg558108.aspx